# Is "final" clause of "task" directive correctly?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to understand how to make `final` clause of the `task` actually work and I found the following example of code in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21996/glmpw.html) link.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define THRESHOLD 5

int fib(int n)
{
  int i, j;

  if (n<2)
  return n;

  #pragma omp task shared(i) firstprivate(n) final(n <= THRESHOLD)
  i=fib(n-1);

  #pragma omp task shared(j) firstprivate(n) final(n <= THRESHOLD)
  j=fib(n-2);

  #pragma omp taskwait
  return i+j;
}


int main()
{
  int n = 30;
  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_num_threads(4);

  #pragma omp parallel shared(n)
  {
     #pragma omp single
     printf ("fib(%d) = %d\n", n, fib(n));
  }
}
```

But when I check the value of `n` by debugging, I notice that apparently the recursive functions are still being called even when the condition `n <= THRESHOLD` is true. So, my question is, am I misunderstanding something or the there's something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens when you call `final` is that the tasks that are spawned out of this one do not make a new task out of it.

From [Specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu46.html#x70-2000002.10.1):

> **[§ 2.10.1  task Construct]** When a final clause is present on a task construct and the final clause expression
>   evaluates to true, the generated task will be a final task. All task constructs
>   encountered during execution of a final task will generate final and included tasks. Note
>   that the use of a variable in a final clause expression of a task construct causes an
>   implicit reference to the variable in all enclosing constructs.

Where a final task is:

> A task that forces all of its child tasks to become final and included tasks.

and included task is:

> A task for which execution is sequentially included in the generating task region.
>   That is, an included task is undeferred and executed immediately by the
>   encountering thread.

In your case that means:
if in this task the `THREASHOLD` is met there are new tasks genereated with `n-1` and `n-2` are spawned and those tasks do not generate new tasks when coming to the recursive call but do still call the functions in 'old fashioned' function call way.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to ask another question. How can I understand if the variable that I put in the `final` clause to check the threshold should be set to `firstprivate` or `shared`?

Comment: my first guess would be that it depends on the rest of your code what you need. but as `The if clause expression and the final clause expression are evaluated in the context outside of the task construct, and no ordering of those evaluations is specified.` I would assume you not use shared since it would be nondeterministic which value is read at evaluation time